# Migrating disqus comments from non drupal site to drupal 7 site

Tags: 7, migrations, comments

I have installed an set up Disqus (add shortname and public key). How can i show/migrate my old comments to my new drupal site.

Answer (score 2):

Disqus offers variety of migration tools depending on your needs - https://help.disqus.com/customer/en/portal/articles/286778-migration-tools. I performed migration of comment threads from static website to Drupal 7 recently. Main change to the pages with comments was new clean URLs, so in my case all I needed to do is to use [URL mapper tool](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/912757-url-mapper). It is very straight forward and comment threads were migrated in minutes.